# How to get all the posts related to a particular topic in reddit?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I was trying to get all the posts related to a particular topic example "cricket" from reddit using praw ,but you have to go through every subreddit, is there any chance we can get this without manually entering the name of the subreddits

Comment: What does "related to a topic" mean?  Do reddit posts have topic tags, as they do here on Slashdot?  Or would you need to search the title and/or full text of every post?

Comment: I would go with texts ,like the post which has "cricket" in it

Comment: What about `reddit.subreddit('all').search('cricket')`

Comment: Hey that worked. ,                                                                                                subreddit = reddit.subreddit('all').search('cricket').top(limit=1000),any idea why this doesn't work,(error: AttributeError: 'ListingGenerator' object has no attribute 'top'
)